# How to Use ServeMux with ServerConn?

Tags: http, go, server, servemux

Im creating a Networking API and want people to be able to route requests to specific endpoints using a [ServeMux](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ServeMux). Instead of using a [Server](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Server) instance, I need to use my own low level [ServerConn](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httputil/#ServerConn). This is because I am receiving both incoming HTTP requests and plain text data from the same port.

The problem, however, is that if I want to forward a request using my ServeMux, I would use it's [ServeHTTP](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ServeMux.ServeHTTP) method. For this, I need to provide a ResponseWriter, which I don't know how to create an instance of since it is an interface, not a struct. Should a I create my own ResponseWriter struct? Is there one given by the Golang Standard Library? Or is there an alternate solution to this altogether?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would avoid doing this altogether if at all possible. Mixing protocols on the same connection is bound to lead to hard-to-trace bugs, and unexpected behavior. If you really want to do it, and have all the http/1.1 mechanisms work correctly, leave as much as possible to the http package.

Since ResponseWriter is an interface, you would implement your own type to satisfy it. Look at the unexported `response` type in the http package for a full example. There's a lot to get right, and using it in combination with a ServerConn (which is documented as "do no use") is probably not a good idea.

The place to do this at a lower level would be in `Accept` inside the Server's `net.Listener`. Since you're going to have to parse the start of every request twice, you would need a `net.Conn` that can be "rewound" partly.

Make yourself a net.Listener that checks the start of the stream on a new connection, and if it looks like an http request, return a `net.Conn` that replays the first chunk you read off the wire on its first Reads. Something like:

```
type replayConn struct {
    net.Conn
    buf []byte
    pos int
}

func (c *replayConn) Read(b []byte) (int, error) {
    if c.pos < len(c.buf) {
        n := copy(b, c.buf[c.pos:])
        c.pos += n
        return n, nil
    }
    return c.Conn.Read(b)
}
```

If the connection isn't http, then send the connection off to your other type of handler, and continue blocking on `Accept`.

Comment: Agreed, thanks for such a comprehensive answer! And yeah, I realize that this is certainly not best practice for Go code or just Networking in general, but at this point Im just trying to make a quick refactor for some existing code. I think Ill go with creating a custom net.Conn interface and a custom net.Listener so I can just use a net.Server and have it listening on my custom net.Listener. That way I don't need to deal with creating a custom ResponseWriter, which may be problematic.
But all things said, I agree, this is a total hack. Good thing this isn't production code or anything though